# Creating Read-only logs with python

Tags: python, linux, logging, permissions

I am writing a python script that needs to make a log entry whenever it's invoked. The log created by the script must not be changeable by the user (except root) who invoked the script. I tried the syslog module and while this does exactly what I want in terms of file permissions, I need to be able to put the resulting log file in an arbitrary location. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I see you are on linux,

Depending on which filesystem you are using, you may be able to use the `chattr` command. You can make files that are append only by setting the `a` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Run your script with [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) root.

Comment: Having a script setuid root just to make a log entry is definitely NOT a good idea.

Comment: I believe this got me started in the right direction. As I understand in, creating a C wrapper binary for the script and then setuid root on it is more secure, right?